# Swift Map Variable Disappears

Tags: swift, mkmapview, mapkit, viewdidload, mkmapviewdelegate

I am trying to set up a map that zooms in on a location. Everything should be fine, but the map becomes unexpectedly nil and I can't figure out why.

```
@IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!

var numberOfAnnotations = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {

    numberOfAnnotations = 0

    var locationManager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()

    map = MKMapView()

    println(map)

    locationManager.delegate = self

    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    map.showsUserLocation = true

    var location = locationManager.location.coordinate

    var span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)

    println(location.latitude)
    println(location.longitude)

    var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)

    println(region.center.longitude)
    println(region.span.latitudeDelta)
    println(map)

    map.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    println(map)
    println(map.description)

    var longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "addAnnotationToMap:")
    // duration required to place a pin is .75 seconds
    longPress.minimumPressDuration = 0.75


    map.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)

    map.delegate = self

    super.viewDidLoad()

}
```

The print lines that it produces are as follows and it crashes on the last println(map.description) and was crashing at map.addGestureRecognizer before that.

```
<MKMapView: 0x15fb0400; frame = (0 0; 0 0); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x15fb0350>>
42.7881728503759
-86.1060027215381
-86.1060027215381
0.01
<MKMapView: 0x15fb0400; frame = (0 0; 0 0); clipsToBounds = YES; layer =<CALayer: 0x15fb0350>>
nil
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Anyone have any idea why this would be happening?

Comment: call this method at the top super.viewDidLoad() at viewDidLoad and why do you need this line   map = MKMapView()?

Comment: Some lines are not required, but anyway try to follow those suggestions. Place `super.viewDidLoad()` at the top of the method ? Set the `map.delegate = self` just after it ? Declare your map as `strong` instead of `weak` ?

Comment: super.viewDidLoad is getting called at the bottom because we have a tab system in it that will get covered up by the map if we don't.  The map = MKMapView() is needed to initialize the variable.

Comment: did you try what i said...?

Comment: Yes and moving the super.viewDidLoad up top did nothing and removing the initialization of map made it crash as soon as the map variable was used at map.showsUserLocation = true